# How to get value from input element from this html using JavaScript and also changing the background of the input element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need the javascript to change the background of input element to either red if the number greater than the preceding number or red if it is less than the preceding number

The value from the input element in html should be in array, then javascript should analyse the array and make the input element background green if the number is greater than the preceding number and then red if it less than the preceding number

The HTML

```
 <form>
   <input type="number" class="display" value="" id= "seat-1">
   <input type="number" class="display" value="" id= "seat-2">
   <input type="number" class="display" value="" id= "seat-3">
   <input type="number" class="display" value="" id= "seat-4">  
   <input type="number" class="display" value="" id= "seat-5">
   <input type="number" class="display" value="" id= "seat-6">
 </form>
```

The Javascript to get the value

```
 let seat1 = document.getElementById("seat-1").value;
 let seat2 = document.getElementById("seat-2").value;
 let seat3 = document.getElementById("seat-3").value;
 let seat4 = document.getElementById("seat-4").value;
 let seat5 = document.getElementById("seat-5").value;
 let seat6 = document.getElementById("seat-6").value;
```

The Javascript to make it an array and print red or green at the input background

```
 let seatRow1 = [ seat1,  seat2, seat3, seat4, seat5, seat6];

    for (let i = 0; i <  seatRow1.length;   i++) {

      if ( (seatRow1[i + 1]) > seatRow1[i]) {
       document.getElementByClassName("display").style.backgroundColor = 
          "green";
            }
      else { 
       document.getElementByClassName("display").style.backgroundColor = 
     "red";
     }
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be vanilla js?

Comment: (jQuery would make it a whole lot simpler to listen to changes in the form)

Comment: No, it is not in Vanilla Js and it has to be in core javascript

Comment: One additional side note, there is a typo in your method `getElementsByClassName()` (Elements is plural) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName (and it returns a HTMLCollection (multiple elements) so you would need to change how you set properties on them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than getting the element values on page load, you will need to check the values whenever one of them changes (since the values at page load will likely change as the user inputs information). One way to do that would be to listen on the `input` event and then check the value of the changed input and compare it to its siblings. For example:

```js
const changeBackground = (elem, v1, v2) => {
  if (v1 < v2) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else if (v1 > v2) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }
};

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (let input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    const target = event.currentTarget;
    const value = parseFloat(target.value);
    const prev = target.previousElementSibling;
    const next = target.nextElementSibling;
    if (prev) {
      changeBackground(target, value, parseFloat(prev.value));
    }
    
    if (next) {
      changeBackground(next, parseFloat(next.value), value);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" value="">
  <input type="number" value="">
  <input type="number" value="">
  <input type="number" value="">
  <input type="number" value="">
  <input type="number" value="">
</form>
```